# Proof for $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r(r!)=\sum_{r=1}^{n}[(r+1)!-r!]=(n+1)!-1$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, factorial

I came across the form $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r(r!)=\sum_{r=1}^{n}[(r+1)!-r!]=(n+1)!-1$ while solving a question in determinants. How do we get to the formula stated above?

Comment: Gosper's algorithm can do this nicely; see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm

Comment: $(r+1)! - r!$ = $(r+1)r! - r! = (r+1-1)r! = r(r!)$ and it's a telescoping sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=n_0}^{N}{(a_{k+1}-a_k)}=a_{N+1}-a_{n_0}$$ 
$\underline{Derivation}$
One can proof that by Induction. Here’s another way.

$$\sum_{k=n_0}^{N}{(a_{k+1}-a_k)}= \sum_{k=n_0}^{N}a_{k+1}-\sum_{k=n_0}^{N}{a_k}$$ 
$$=\sum_{k=n_{0}+1}^{N+1}a_k-\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{N}{a_k}-a_{n_0}$$
$$=a_{N +1}-a_{n_0}+\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{N}{a_k}-\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{N}{a_k}$$
$$=a_{N+1}-a_{n_0}$$